# Red5 install on CentOS build.xml does not exist?

Tags: centos, media, red5, stream

http://nocreativity.com/blog/how-to-install-red5-on-centos-5-the-complete-guide

I have followed this tutorial for installing Red5 line by line however I have just got to compiling the Red5 code I get the following error.

```
[root@server1 red5]# ant prepare
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

What it is saying is correct, the dir /usr/local/red5 does not contain build.xml however I don't know if it is trying to get the build.xml from this directory. I am a complete noob to CentOS, I have been searching for about an hour now but cannot find a solution.

---

EDIT (NOW FIXED)

---

I just downloaded the files directly from red5. For anyone else that wants to do this:

> wget http://www.red5.org/downloads/red5/1_0_1/red5-1.0.1.tar.gz
>   tar zxvf red5-1.0.1.tar.gz
>   mv /usr/local/red5-server-1.0 /usr/local/red5

After this run red5.sh in the red5 directory and everything should run correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to build red5, grab the source from [github](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server) and use Maven. Ant has not been supported for several versions now. For [build instructions](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server#build-from-source) and further [details](https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki/Build-Errors).